# Generate API Keys Programatically in Shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

I am trying to implement automatic API keys generation in Shopify.

As [shown here in WooCommerce](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#rest-api-keys), the second example explains how to get keys from the API.

I wanted to know if there is that option in Shopify. I want to generate customers API keys programatically, instead of manually going through the Partner portal.

Is this possible?

Comment: You seem to be mixing multiple things here. What is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: The second authentication method shown in WooCommerce (generate api keys via API) with Shopify.